# Google Account Deleted, can't log in to other acccount

Tags: support, login, google-openid

My other Stack Exchange account Find Me In The Woods was linked to a google account of mine that was accidentally deleted. I need to recover the account. I know my old google account email and password. Can anyone help me get back in to my old account?

Comment: It would be best to contact the team directly on this one. Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.